# Java: Matching close numbers with a threshold

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Say you have *n* arrays with various `Integer`  values in each. How can I use Java to find integers that are within *m* numbers from each other?

For example:

Array 1: `22, 23, 210, 221, 231, 236, 237, 251, 254, 278, 300, 316, 320`

Array 2: `230`

Array 3: `365, 366, 367, 373, 410, 413, 415, 417, 419`

I wish to have an algorithm that analyzes these given arrays with a value of `m=1` and outputs the pair `231:Array1, 230:Array2`. What is the best approach?

Comment: what about numbers in the same array that are within m?

Comment: Clusters need to be values from different arrays that are m from *each other*

Comment: The difference must be exactly `m` or less or equal to `m`? Also a cluster has exactly two numbers or up to `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

**1. Define arrays**:

```
int [] arr1 = {22, 23, 210, 221, 231, 236, 237, 251, 254, 278, 300, 316, 320};
int [] arr2 = {230};
int [] arr3 = {365, 366, 367, 373, 410, 413, 415, 417, 419};
```

**2. Put all the arrays into sets**:

```
List<Set<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<>();
addSets(sets, arr1, arr2, arr3);

// Time: O(n * k) where n=number of arrays and k=size of largest array
private static void addSets(List<Set<Integer>> sets, int [] ... arrs)
{
    for (int [] arr : arrs)
    {
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i : arr)
        {
            s.add(i);
        }
        sets.add(s);
    }
}
```

**3. Define the m**:

```
int m = 1;
```

**4. Find the clusters**:

```
List<String> pairs = findClusters(sets, m);

// Time: O(n^2 * k) where n=number of arrays and k=size of largest array
private static List<String> findClusters(List<Set<Integer>> sets, int m)
{
    // holds the pairs
    List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < sets.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        Set<Integer> primary = sets.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < sets.size(); j++)
        {
            Set<Integer> secondary = sets.get(j);

            for (int p : primary)
            {
                if (secondary.contains(p - m))
                {
                    pairs.add(p + ", " + (p-m));
                }
                if (secondary.contains(p + m))
                {
                    pairs.add(p + ", " + (p+m));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

**5. Print the pairs**:

```
for (String pair : pairs)
    System.out.println(pair);
```

**Total Runtime**:

```
O((k * n) + (k * n^2))
```

Comment: **within m numbers** . I think this will only give pairs with `m` distance but in question It is clearly mentioned that OP requires all pairs within **m** distance.

Comment: This approach is the easiest to understand, and defines the algorithm well. I will combine the pairs into an array, as I need an output that is not necessarily a pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it using the java8 streams:

```
public class Main{

    // This will give the stream of the data points from selected datasets
    public static Stream<List<Integer>> getPairs(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){
        return a.stream().flatMap(itemA -> b.stream().map(itemB -> Arrays.asList(itemA, itemB)));
    }

    // This will create the combination of datasets
    public static Stream<List<List<Integer>>> get(List<List<Integer>> dataSet) {
        return IntStream.range(0, dataSet.size()).boxed()
                .flatMap(i -> dataSet.subList(i+1, dataSet.size()).stream()
                        .map(secondry -> Arrays.asList(dataSet.get(i), secondry)));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // data sets 
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(22, 23, 210, 221, 231, 236, 237, 251, 254, 278, 300, 316, 320);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(230);
        List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(365, 366, 367, 373, 410, 413, 415, 417, 419);

        // prepare dataset by adding any number of data cluster
        List<List<Integer>> dataset = Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3);

        // create the required predicate and pass it to next statement
        Predicate<List<Integer>> predicate = points -> points.get(1) - points.get(0) == 1 || points.get(0) - points.get(1) == 1; 

        get(dataset).flatMap(datapair -> getPairs(datapair.get(0), datapair.get(1)))
                .filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

output:

```
[231, 230]
```

You can run the [code here](https://repl.it/HxIx/0).

Comment: This is a good approach, but how can I change this to return arbitrary length arrays of close numbers? For example, if 230 were in Array 3, the return value should be [231, 230, 231].

Comment: @jshapy8 I assumed the output for the data points in two cluster. For arbitrary length the approach will change.

Comment: I suppose it is possible to combine the pairs into an array, removing duplicates as we go.

Comment: @jshapy8 yes that is a good suggestion, if we add the array info to the data point (where it belongs) and then again compare the merge the result then it is might possible.

Comment: Their position in the resulting array will indicate where the point belongs (first position = first array, second position = second array) etc. No two numbers from a single array should end up in the resulting array. These values are line numbers of where a word occurred in a dataset and the return value is used to find a sentence in the dataset that contains all of those words (occurrences of words in a dataset are what the arrays are in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This is an O(m+n) solution for each pair of arrays. It assumes that all the arrays are sorted.

```
input x[m], y[n], threshold
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i<m && j<n) {
    if ( abs(x[i]-y[j]) <= threshold) {
        return true;
    }
    if (x[i] <= y[j]) {
        i++;
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
```

complexity: O(n + m)

Note that you could convert this to one loop that considers all the arrays by using a heap and its complexity will be O(n*log(k)) where n is the total size over all arrays and k is the number of arrays.

Comment: But how about for n arrays, not just two?

Comment: @jshapy8 Use a heap to keep track of each current element (actually an object containing the element and the index of the array) from each of the arrays as mentioned in my comment.